# Integrating Magento with a CRM software

Tags: zend-framework, magento, e-commerce, crm

I am looking for the most suitable and easy to configure solution that would integrate Magento with a CRM.

Which CRM is more suitable and compatible with Magento?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

We are using SugarCRM right now with Magento and it works very well.  The connector is like $200 and does everything we need.

http://www.vivendoconnect.com/crm/sugarcrm-standard-extension.html was where we got it

Answer (score 0):

I have heard of [Microsoft Dynamics](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/default.aspx), [Highrise](http://highrisehq.com/) & [Zendesk](http://www.zendesk.com/) CRMs as well, but how much are they manageable through Magento extensions is my major concern.

Also as "**Josh**" said, there are extensions for [SugarCRM](http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/).
There are also extensions for other famous CRMs as well like [Salesforce](http://www.salesforce.com/) & [viger](http://www.vtiger.com/) in Magento.

May be this post is old, but still I'm interested in knowing the details of the possibility of the integration as well.

Hope it helps.